# how to pass two parameter during page redirect in php without using session

Tags: php, html

how to pass two parameter during page redirect in php without using session
I tried below steps but its not working:

```
header("Location: viewtableinform.php?action=" .$action & "$fname=" .$fname);
```

Comment: Because at least I see syntax errors here.

Comment: `.$action & "$fname` should be `.$action . "&fname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass parameter like this (Query string with Concatenation)

```
header("Location: viewtableinform.php?action=".$action."&fname=".$fname);
```

for more information please read [Header Mnaual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: accept this answer. In future this question is useful for others users

Answer (score 1):

It should like

`header("Location: viewtableinform.php?action=$action&fname=$fname");`

Answer (score -1):

Try following code.Use the ampersand & to glue variables together:

```
header("Location: viewtableinform.php?action=$action&fname=$fname");
            //                      ^ start of vars      ^next var
```

Answer (score -1):

it should be something like this

```
header("Location: viewtableinform.php?action=".$action."&fname=".$fname);
```